# Trying to make a random array that I can call 5 times, and that i can test against a user input

Tags: java, arrays, random

Need some help trying to set up this assignment. I am not to good with arrays, nor setting up methods to be used in the main. I need to make an array of 10 random numbers 1-100, that can be compared to the user input. I only need the comparison true/false to display. Here is what I have.
I get several errors in trying to print, so i haven't even tried to compare it to the user input yet.
Thanks,

```
import java.util.*;


public class Final {


public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.print("Enter Player's Free Throw Percentage: ");
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        int percent = input.nextInt();
        print(shots);
}


public  int [] getRandomNumbers(){
    int [] shots = new int [10];
    Random r = new Random();
    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        shots[i] = r.nextInt(100);
    return shots;
```

}

```
public static void print(int shots[]) {
    for (int i=0; i<shots.length; i++) {
        System.out.print(shots[i]);
        if (i < shots.length-1) {
            System.out.print(", ");
    }
        else {
            System.out.println("");
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: 1)  Format your code.  2) Don't you think it would help to tell us what the errors are, or are we just supposed to guess?

Comment: What errors do you have?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As commentors said, please provide error messages.

However, I can pick out several issues just for starters.  Let's look at your main method...

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.print("Enter Player's Free Throw Percentage: ");
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    int percent = input.nextInt();
    print int [](shots);

    }
```

In this call to the print method, why do you have `int []` in there?  Are you trying to cast something to an int array?  Anyways, that has to come out.

Also, you are passing the print method some `shots` variable that doesn't exist.

Your print method takes an int array as its only argument, so you have to pass it a valid int array.  Perhaps you meant to call `getRandomNumbers()` and pass the int array that it returns to the print method?

Also, what's with the nested classes you're showing.  You have this class `Final` with another class `ShotClass` defined inside of it.  And your closing brackets are all out of whack.

In short, you need to do as the comments ask and format your code and then work through each individual error message, because you've got a whole lot to fix.

***EDIT***

I'm not sure if I'm doing you more harm than good by giving you the answer to your homework assignment, but I feel for you so here it is.  Please just look very carefully at the exact differences between what you posted in your question and what I show below.  There's several mistakes you made, including bad syntax and a misunderstanding of how scope works, and I can't properly explain all the problems without typing several pages, so I hope you can learn from this example instead...

```
import java.util.*;

public class Final {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.print("Enter Player's Free Throw Percentage: ");
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    int percent = input.nextInt();
    int[] shots = getRandomNumbers();
    print(shots);
  }

  public static int[] getRandomNumbers(){
    int [] shots = new int [10];
    Random r = new Random();
    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
      shots[i] = r.nextInt(100);
    }
    return shots;
  }

  public static void print(int[] shots) {
    for (int i=0; i<shots.length; i++) {
      System.out.print(shots[i]);
      if (i < shots.length-1) {
        System.out.print(", ");
      }
      else {
        System.out.println("");
      }
    }
  }

}//END class
```

Comment: im very confused, i indented the 4 spaces so not sure why its not formatted correctly. the error is trying to print out shot. Shot is name of the variable in the random array. That is what i need to reference in the code. Sorry very new to this and been working on this for a few days =. I originally just made everything run in a main method and it was to clunky. also how do I post additional code  to show?

Comment: I updated the code and formatted, correctly I think. I don't get errors when compiling now, but I cannon't get it to print either. I keep getting cannot find symbol "shots". I thought shots was defined as the new int array so now im confused.

Comment: That's much closer to being correct, but there's no way what you posted compiles.  In your main method, when you call print(shots), that shots variable doesn't exist in the scope of your main method.  Try print(getRandomNumbers()) instead.

Comment: your correct Jim I removed the print (shots) and it complies. That is the issue I am still having is getting it to print, even after changing it to (getRandomNumbers()) I get same error. I thought the point of defining the Int [] to be shots was so it can be called by the name shots later?

Comment: You are not calling your getRandomNumbers method anywhere.  Call it to get your int array, then pass the returned int array to your print method.

Comment: Im confused, I though by telling the method to return shots. That the print method calls the return of the getRandomNumbers, (which should be shots) to print in the main.

Comment: You have some basic misunderstandings of how scope works in object oriented programming languages.  You should go read up on it.  Try Head First Java or some other beginner Java book, and specifically read up on the concept of scope.

Comment: I will do that but can you explain to me what i need to change? I have read through my book for class and am still confused on what is wrong, this is only about 1/5 of the total assignment and its due tomorrow. I wrote it all in one giant main method and it works, but my professor said i need to make methods to call in the main to run instead to get full credit. I thought i am to call the name of the Int array to print?

Comment: See my edit.  I gave you the answer; please make sure you learn from it!

Comment: Thank you , i see that i forgot a set of brackets and that i needed to call the int [] in the main to allow it to pull the print.